# Is it normal to get truncated identifiers after applying SQL scema of RegaDB?

Tags: hiv

*This question was also asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9562091/)*

I am trying to set up [**RegaDB**](https://rega.kuleuven.be/cev/regadb) on my **CentOS** system, and I have installed **PostgreSQL** via `conda`. I followed the **RegaDB** installation manual to configure the **PostgreSQL** database. However, when I have applied the *postgresSchema.sql* schema from the **RegaDB** software package, I noticed several `NOTICE` messages about truncated identifiers.

Here is a sample of the output I received:

```
psql:postgresSchema.sql:25: NOTICE:  identifier "query_definition_parameter_type_query_definition_parameter_type_ii_seq" will be truncated to "query_definition_parameter_type_query_definition_parameter_type"
psql:postgresSchema.sql:27: NOTICE:  identifier "query_definition_run_parameter_query_definition_run_parameter_ii_seq" will be truncated to "query_definition_run_parameter_query_definition_run_parameter_i"
psql:postgresSchema.sql:29: NOTICE:  identifier "resistance_interpretation_template_resistance_interpretation_template_ii_seq" will be truncated to "resistance_interpretation_template_resistance_interpretation_te"
```

I understand that **PostgreSQL** has a maximum identifier length of *63* bytes, and identifiers exceeding this limit will be truncated. My question is whether these truncated identifiers will cause any issues with the proper functioning of **RegaDB**. If so, what would be the best approach to fix this issue?

I would appreciate any guidance on this matter, and if there are any additional precautions or testing measures I should take to ensure **RegaDB** functions as expected.

Best regards,

Comment: Hi @Vovin I would make sure RegaDB is not abandonware. Its [github](https://github.com/plibin/regadb) hasn't been updated for 9 years. PostgreSQL will have been revised many times since then and will not be the version used to develop RegaDB. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: @M__ I suppose that newer versions of **PostgreSQL** (as well as **Tomcat**) actually caused a bunch of my fail attempts to run **RegaDB**. But the maximum length of identifiers is a substantially base thing in **PostgreSQL**, as it is set by the constant `NAMEDATALEN` at the compilation step.